# symfony2: how to write the methods for a many to many relationship?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I've created these two models below (Author and Book) associated through a many to many relationship. Then I have generated the crud methods.

The problem: when I try to create or save an author using the new or edit form, it doesn't save the books.

```
namespace Prueba\FrontendBundle\Entity;

use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="author")
 */
class Author
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\GeneratedValue @ORM\Column(type="integer") **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */ 
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="authors")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="author_book")
     */
    protected $books;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->books = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }


    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->books;
    }

    public function addBook($book)
    {
        $this->books[] = $book;
    }

    public function setBooks($books)
    {
        $this->books = $books;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

--------------

namespace Prueba\FrontendBundle\Entity; 

use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="book")
*/
class Book 
{
     /** @ORM\Id @ORM\GeneratedValue @ORM\Column(type="integer") **/
     protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */ 
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="books")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="author_book")
     */
    protected $authors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authors = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        //die("fadsfadsff");
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getAuthors()
    {
        //die();
        return $this->authors;
    }

    public function addAuthor($authors)
    {
        die();//Here is not entering after editing a book!!!!! why????
        $this->authors = $authors;
    }

    public function setAuthors($authors)
    {
        die();//Here is not entering after editing a book!!!!! why????
        $this->authors = $authors;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's the cause of your problem, but you specified `inversedBy` in both the entities.

It should be:

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="authors")
     */
    protected $books;
}
```

Because an author *owns* the books.

And

```
class Book
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Author", mappedBy="books")
     */
    protected $authors;
}
```

Because a book *belongs* to an author.

Comment: Just to clarify this is true in this particular problem, but the owning side is just a convention: you can decide what should be the owner based on how you work with entities. http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: THANKS! Yes, you are right..I thought the position of 'inversedBy' and 'mappedBy' was not important, but I was wrong..

Comment: Anyway, im curious: why the coding flow is not entering in addAuthor() or setAuthors()?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: After submitting the form to edit a book, I expected the addAuthor() or setAuthors() methods were called in the same way that getAuthors() is called when I call the edit action to show the form to edit the book.

Comment: Did you change or add an author? If you didn't, it's normal that it doesn't enter `addAuthor()` and `setAuthors()`. But if you did, I can't say why since I don't have the code in front of me (and it's been a while that I didn't use Symfony2 or Doctrine2 :) ). Good luck!

Comment: One more thing: do you know how can I set both classes as owning and inverse side in the same time? It that way in the forms I could associate books to authors and authors to books.

Comment: An entity cannot be the reverse side and the owning side of the same another entity at the same time. Though, there's no reason you can't associate authors to books. I hope I'am not saying crap, so please try it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Cascaded persistence is not automatic, and you haven't specified any [cascade rules](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="authors", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="author_book")
 */
protected $books;
```

I've not used cascading with ManyToMany associations myself, but it should work